# Trigonometric Inequalities

Tags: trigonometry

If $$a\sin A+b\sin B+c\sin C=k$$ 
then the minimum value of $$\sin^2A + \sin^2B + \sin^2C =?$$

ATTEMPT-

I tried to use A.M-R.M.S inequality but it didn't help

Comment: do you know lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$(\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge(a\sin A+b\sin B+c\sin C)^2$$
So:
$$\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C\ge\frac{k}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$

Comment: How to you get the first step ? Can you explain it

Comment: @HimanshuArora Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for real numbers: $(a^2+b^2+c^2...)(a_0^2+b_0^2+c_0^2+...)\geq(aa_0+bb_0+cc_0+...)^2$